# Please help with this word problem involving trigonometry

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

A small aircraft has a glide ration of 15:1. (The glide ratio means the plane moves 15 units horizontally for every one unit elevation). You are exactly in the middle of a 3.0 mile diameter lake at 500 ft when the fuel supply is exhausted. You see a gravel road to the dock and must decide wether to try a ground or water landing.

Comment: Your question will be more readily received by the community if you show what you've tried and precisely where you are having difficulty.

Comment: @AustinMohr:  While your comment is correct, my experience is that the hard part of word problems is the translation to mathematics, so it is hard to articulate what the problem is.  That said, life is a word problem.

Comment: @RossMillikan I agree, but we can still encourage users to indicate something like "I am having difficulty setting this problem up" if that is the case.

Comment: @AustinMohr:  While often the case, I think that statement is no help to providing a useful answer.  I am not a professional teacher, but I see questions on this site about word problems in the context of "I am having difficulty setting this problem up".  If OP could set the problem up, I would hope we would see that.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  How far to the shore?  How far do you glide?  Remember that 1 mile =5280 feet (are you using statute miles, not nautical miles? Does it matter?).